# What should I do in this Kotlin code to print number in series like 1,2,3 ..5

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am having trouble in printing number in series like 1,2,3,4,5 through for loop. I have code a mark sheet where we take numbers as input from user and then print them through for loop like Subject 1 is = 33

```
 val x = arrayListOf<String>()
 for (i in 0..4) {
     println("Enter Marks of Subject ${i+1}")
     x.add(readLine()!!)
 }

 for(Marks in x) {
     for(f in 0..0) {
         println("Subject ${f + 1} is $Marks")
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Put any related code **formatted** into your queston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loop never updates the value of `f` so you are always getting the same value of `f = 0 + 1`. Anyway, you can do the same operation with a single loop, like so:

```
for(i in 0 until x.size) {
    println("Subject ${i+1} is ${x[i]}")
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and its work but the problem is it is starting from zero like Subject 0 is instead of subject 1

Comment: @BilalKhan you are right, I have edited my answer so now Subject index starts from 1

Comment: Hey Alex could you please help me in the code below? I want it to run while loop for only three time. How to do that?

var y= 3

do{
    println("Enter Any Number")
    val x= readLine()!!.toInt()
    var z = true
    if (x==y){
        z=false
    }

} while (z)
println("You Guessed Right")

Comment: @BilalKhan, being this an unrelated question with your question above, you should ask as a new question on StackOverflow. Take in mind that comments are not to answer questions, so, ask a new question and I will help you

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question:

```
for (f in 0..x.size - 1)
    println("Subject ${f+1} is ${x[f]}")
```

you don't need the outer loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yeah its working but could you please explain me this piece of code for (f in 0..x.size - 1) . I want to know purpose of -1 here?

Comment: x is an array of x.size elements which are numbered 0, 1, 2, ... so the last one, the nth element has index = x.size - 1. The indexing of collections is zero=based